# Can't use a generic method on a swift protocol type

Tags: swift, generics

I have a protocol with primary associated type

```swift
public protocol MyProtocol<Value> {
    associatedtype Value: Codable

    static var key: String { get }

    // I can't call this method with an array of it
    static func transform(value: Value) -> Int
}
```

but this kind of code doesn't compile with:

```
public func transformed(keys: [any MyProtocol.Type]) -> [Int] {
    return keys.compactMap { key -> Int? in
        // give me a object of type MyProtocol.Value
        guard let value = getValue(key) else { return nil } 

        return key.transform(value: value) // error here
    }
}
```

I got an error :

`Member 'transform' cannot be used on value of type 'any MyProtocol.Type'; consider using a generic constraint instead`.

Any advice ?

Thanks !

EDIT :

I use the type itself as the key. This is what is done for example with `EnvironmentKey` implementation on SwiftUI:

```swift
private struct MyEnvironmentKey: EnvironmentKey {
    static let defaultValue: String = "Default value"
}

extension EnvironmentValues {
    var myCustomValue: String {
        get { self[MyEnvironmentKey.self] }
        set { self[MyEnvironmentKey.self] = newValue }
    }
}
```

As you see this is the type used as a key, not an instance of it.
My goal is to have an "dictionary" type that uses MyProtocol as a Key.
in my case, I have several keys based on this idea. here is a complete minimal example:

```swift
public protocol ProtocolKey {
    associatedtype Value: Codable

    static var key: String { get }

    static func predicate(value: Value) -> NSPredicate
}

public struct ValuesContainer {
    let storage: [String: Any]


    // MARK: - getter

    public subscript<Key: ProtocolKey>(key: Key.Type) -> Key.Value? {
        get {
            return storage[key.key] as? Key.Value
        }
    }

    public func predicates(keys: [any ProtocolKey.Type]) -> [NSPredicate] { // the previously named func transformed
        // what to do here ?
    }
}

// MARK: - Implementation

struct AssigneeKey: ProtocolKey {
    typealias Value = String
    static var key: String { "assignee" }

    static func predicate(value: String) -> NSPredicate {
        return NSPredicate(value: true)
    }
}

struct CountKey: ProtocolKey {
    typealias Value = Int
    static var key: String { "count" }

    static func predicate(value: Int) -> NSPredicate {
        return NSPredicate(value: false)
    }
}
```

Comment: You haven't included `transform`. Also, I think you likely mean `any MyProtocol` rather than `any MyProtocol.Type`, but without a [mre], it's hard to say.

Comment: Please fix your code: what is `getValue(key)`? why key and transform are `static`, yet you are trying to use them on an instance? (or whatever you are doing makes no sense)

Comment: This can't really work. With `[any MyProtocol]`, you're saying "An array of any objects that conform to MyProtocol". There's no guarantee that their `Value` is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way by creating a constrained intermediate method.
In the `ValuesContainer` of the example:

```swift
    func predicate<Key: ProtocolKey>(key: Key.Type) -> NSPredicate? {
        guard let value = self[key] else { return nil }

        return key.predicate(value: value)
    }

    public func predicates(keys: [any ProtocolKey.Type]) -> [NSPredicate] {
        return keys.compactMap { key -> NSPredicate? in
            self.predicate(key: key)
        }
    }
```